# Jekyll/Liquid: Include compiled SASS inline in template

Tags: sass, jekyll, liquid

For performance reasons, I want to inline my CSS in the HTML files generated by Jekyll. Naively, I tried:

```
<style type="text/css">
  {% include main.scss %}
</style>
```

The trouble is, that includes the source file (which just defines variables and includes other files), not the compiled CSS. How can I get the compiled CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Jekyll `scssify` filter to the rescue :

```
  <style type="text/css">
    {% capture sass_file %}
      {% include main.scss %}
    {% endcapture %}
    {{ sass_file | scssify }}
  </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, `scssify` can't handle `@import` statements, which means that I can't use it unless I want to manually merge all my files together into one monstrosity. It also can't handle `@charset`, though that isn't likely to be much of an issue as the server will send the correct charset in the headers.

Comment: I've just tested this trick and "It works !". I can have a look at your code if you have any repository url to submit.

Comment: I tried it again and discovered that the issue is that `scssify` can't handle files with Jekyll front matter. So, problem solved. Interestingly, the build time for development builds jumped from 2 seconds to 12 seconds. I wonder what will happen in a production build, which currently takes about 5 minutes?